# Why are some desktops locked during a dual monitor set up?

Tags: display, desktop

Sometimes during the dual monitor set up, I can't move a desktop to another monitor. Why??

For example, if I have a dual monitor, I can move desktop 1 to another monitor, but I can't move desktop 2. This happens vice versa.

[image]

I've been living with it for the past 1.5 years but finally got annoyed by it enough to ask it here.

Comment: To have the freedom to swap at will, you need more Desktops than you have displays.

Comment: @Tetsujin It still doesn't work even when I make 10 + desktops

Comment: Then idk, sorry. I don't use independent displays that way, I have mine in pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The space that you want to move to another monitor cannot be active.

For instance if you are currently on "Desktop 1" you can move any space to any monitor except for "Desktop 1."  If you want to move "Desktop 1", you need to switch to a different space and then move it to the monitor you want.

Comment: Yes you are right! What a simple solution I did not realize ‍♂️